# Visual Studio Code Terminal not showing the current c file

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, terminal

I was writing my code and a error occurred "#[include errors detected. please update your includepath. squiggles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6H8B.jpg)", I fixed it but after that the terminal section is not the showing the current file location and I am unable to run the code (evn with the code runner) please! help. See the image by clicking on the link above.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try restarting vscode
2. Try manually editing the workspace settings.

   1. Create a `.vscode` directory
   2. Create a `c_cpp_properties.json` file
   3. Add the following code block to it.

```json
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "includePath": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```